How to perform a Find/Replace on a directory of Excel files in VBA
I am wanting to perform a Find/Replace on all the excel files in a single folder
(that I am prompted to select.)
This is the code:
Sub Find_Replace1() Range("A2:A100000").Replace What:="MyTextString1", Replacement:="MyTextString2" End Sub
How do I open, change, close on all the files in one folder?
I do not know how to program in VBA

Use Dir to identify the files, Workbooks.Open to open them, perform the replacement, Workbook.Close with SaveChanges:=True.
